# Conditionally change background color of table cell

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with many rows. In each row there is a cell with an id of 'overwrite'. If overwrite contains a number > 0 than I would like to change the background color of the cell to red.

I have javascript that looks like this:

```
$('#overwrite').each(function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).text()) > 0) {
        $(this).addClass('records_overwritten');
    }
});
```

This only changes the background color of one cell, and none of the others even though they also contain a value greater than 0. I am a bit confused what the issue is.

Here is an example of a table row:

```
<tr>
  <td>March 18, 2014</td>
  <td>John Smith</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td id="overwrite">1</td>
  <td>56</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You can only use one ID value in a document.

Comment: an id should be unique

Comment: the issue is the duplicate IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an `ID` must be unique on a page — and `$('#overwrite')` would return at most one element — use a class instead of repeated `ID`'s

```
$('.overwrite').each(function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).text(), 10) > 0) {
        $(this).addClass('records_overwritten');
    }
});
```

Furthermore, if the column to check is always the 5<sup>th</sup> `<td>` of every row, you may also avoid to insert unnecessary attributes and you can retrieve those elements with `$('tr td:nth-child(5)')`;

Also note that `parseInt` requires a radix as a second argument

Comment: Fabrizio, I threw your code (and his) into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F2Q3V/).  It still does not work.  If you want to adjust it so it is working and add it to your answer it would probably help Graham a lot.

Comment: @Thomas if you use jQuery code then you must include the jQuery library. Right now in your fiddle no library has been included ;)

Comment: Thanks, I added it and it works.  The link is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F2Q3V/1/) `http://jsfiddle.net/F2Q3V/1/`.  You can add it to your answer if you want.  Hopefully Graham will choose your answer.

Answer (score 1):

change the id to class

```
 <tr>
  <td>March 18, 2014</td>
  <td>John Smith</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td class="overwrite">1</td>
  <td>56</td>
 </tr>
```

and use class selector instead

```
 $('.overwrite').each(function() {.....
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute is assumed to be unique to a page, and so jQuery still stop looking after it finds one. You could get around this by using the following selector `[id="overwrite"]` but you really should be using classes or something.

Answer (score 0):

ID is intented to be unique on page, so $('#ID').each is not a good idea. Maybe you could use class or attr value for identification.

About the background setting: closest() is a good solution here.

`$( ".overwrite" ).closest( "tr" ).css( "background-color", "red" );`